# Which supervised classifiers in scikit-learn are recommended for large datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, large-data, large-files, large-data-volumes

There are many supervised classifier algorithms available in scikit-learn but I couldn't find any information about their scaalbility regarding large datasets. I know that for instance, support vector machines don't behave well with huge datasets, but what about others?
Which supervised/semi-supervised classifier algorithms are most suitable for large datasets?

Comment: For example: everything based on Stochastic gradient descent: ```SGDClassifier``` (includes linear SVM) and probably most of ```linear_model``` if the right methods are chosen (docs). Also ```LinearSVC```. But *huge* is subjective.

Comment: Cf. also the [scikit-learn algorithm cheat sheet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are specifically looking for classifiers in sklearn, you can have a look at this link : [Scaling Strategies for large datasets](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html).

Generally, the classifiers do incremental learning on your dataset by creating mini-batches. Here are some link for reference :

**Incremental Learning links**

- [Advanced ML lecture on Incremental Learning](http://www.ra.cs.uni-tuebingen.de/lehre/ss12/advanced_ml/lecture8.pdf)
- [ML on streaming data](https://blog.bigml.com/2013/03/12/machine-learning-from-streaming-data-two-problems-two-solutions-two-concerns-and-two-lessons/)
- [Incremental Leanring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning)
- [Microsoft paper on Incremental Learning](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0709/0709.3965.pdf)

You can have a look at these classifiers in SKlearn for more info

- [SGD Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier)
- [Passive Agrressive Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.PassiveAggressiveClassifier)
- [Multinomial Naive Bayes Incremental Learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB)
- [BErnoulli Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB)

If your data is given as a stream during input, you can have a look at [Apache Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html) and jump to [MlLib in Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-guide.html) for more info.

You can also have a look at [Feature Hasher](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.FeatureHasher) for large scale feature hashing in sklearn.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8160718/mohammed-kashif thank you, this is great source of information! What about semi-supervised classifiers (LabelPropagation and LabelSpreading), do they behave well with large datasets?

Comment: @zlatko Your Welcome ! Although I am not sure about semi-supervised classifiers. Will need to look that up. Will update you once I find something relevant.

Comment: How these incremental classifiers behave if standard fit method is used instead of partial_fit? Any performance difference to other algorithms if partial_fit is not used?

Answer (score 0):

By huge datasets you mean like the "iris" deafult dataset?

Depending on what you want to do with those algorithms, like training and fitting, for example. 
I am gonna write down the ones I use for BIG datasets, and work fine.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets, svm\n
import numpy as np\n
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV\n
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error\n
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor\n
```

But of course you need to know what do you want to do with them.
Here you can check everything you want to know about these or many more. 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/